# #1005 - Can't create table `musicplayer`.`Albums` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

I'm trying to define some tables with SQL, but when I execute it I have an error. Below there is my code and the error which I receive.

```
CREATE TABLE Artists 
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Albums 
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    releasedate DATE,
    artistid INT,
    genreid INT,
    picture VARCHAR(255),

    CONSTRAINT `fk_albums_artists` 
        FOREIGN KEY (artistid) REFERENCES Artists(id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_albums_genres` 
        FOREIGN KEY (genreid) REFERENCES Genres(id)
);

CREATE TABLE Tracks
(
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    playtime INT NOT NULL,
    albumid INT,

    CONSTRAINT `fk_tracks_album` 
        FOREIGN KEY (albumid) REFERENCES Albums(id)    
);

CREATE table Genres
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Error in my SQL query:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1005 - Can't create table `musicplayer`.`Albums` (errno: 150 "Foreign 
>   key 
>   constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: You need to order the tables so the tables are defined *before* the foreign key definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the tables in order, so the tables are defined *before* they are referenced:

```
CREATE TABLE Artists (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    description varchar(255)
);

CREATE table Genres(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT null,
    name varchar(255) not null
);


CREATE TABLE Albums (
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    releasedate date,
    artistid int,
    genreid int,
    picture varchar(255),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_albums_artists` FOREIGN KEY (artistid) REFERENCES Artists(id),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_albums_genres` FOREIGN KEY (genreid) REFERENCES Genres(id)
);


CREATE TABLE Tracks(
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT null,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    playtime int not null,
    albumid int,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_tracks_album` FOREIGN KEY (albumid) REFERENCES Albums(id)    
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a8fff52f869be4ec01ac2cbbd62611d2) is a db<>fiddle.

You can still have tables that reference each other.  However, you will need to declare such foreign key constraints using `ALTER TABLE` rather than in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  However, you do not need to do this for these table definitions.